# Is there an idiom to say "I don't know how many time is gone"?

Tags: idioms

I would like to know if the sentence **I don't know how many time is gone** makes sense and, if yes, Is there an idiom to say that.

e.g:

> John: You're a programmer expert, I remember when you were young and you used Visual Basic.
>
> Luke: I don't know how many time is gone.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include a context for that phrase?  I'm not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: *Time* in this context is a mass noun, so you can't count it like "many time", you have to say "much time".

Answer (score 2):

"I don't know where the time has gone" is what you want.  At my age, I say this all the time.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot of! Btw, why has gone instead of is gone?

Comment: Wow, that's actually a more difficult question to answer than your actual question, and I can't really think of a good reason other than "that's the idiom".   Instead of "Where has the time gone?" you can say "Where did the time go?"  but "is gone" has a different nuance from either.  Perhaps you should ask that as a separate question?

Comment: Sure, Tomorrow morning I'll do it, It's late now.

Comment: FWIW, the short version of this idiom is "time flies".

Comment: "Is gone", in modern English, is not a verb form, (like "has gone") but an adjectival complement, exactly parallel to the clearly adjectival form "is absent" (which it is nearly synonymous with). It does not look back at the past at all, the was that "has gone" does. [In the English of three or four hundred years ago, "is gone" was a verbal form].

Comment: @ColinFine I'm actually curious if there's a deeper linguistic reason why "has gone" is different from "is gone", like if there's a connection to some other similar grammar structure.

Comment: @Andrew, Early Modern English used forms of "be" to form the perfect of some intransitive verbs, especially ones of motion: "I am come; he is arrived; they are grown tall". Modern English has standardised on forms of "have" for all perfects, so those forms are archaic (though familiar from the King James Bible). French and German continue to work like EME.

Comment: *Have / has / had {past-participle}* allow a logical "space" between a past event and now, where another event can happen.  Sometimes this event is expressed, other times it's impiled, and other times the construct is simply used to mean "really back in the past" or to emphasize something is in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Luke can also use the phrase *time flies*.

> **time flies** *phrase*
>   Used as an observation that time seems to pass very quickly.
>   *‘people say time flies when you're having fun’*
>   *‘my daughter started school in September—oh, how time flies’*
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/time_flies)